# Is there a way to unstub in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Searched the Relish docs, but did not find a way to unstub in RSpec.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to unstub something? Perhaps there's a better approach.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

With new `expect` syntax, `unstub` is deprecated. You can do:

```
# stub
allow(SomeClass).to receive(:a_method)

# do something...

# unstub
allow(SomeClass).to receive(:a_method).and_call_original
```

If the first `allow` contains `.with` or a block, I believe it'll still carry to the next call, so the next `allow` doesn't clear those things.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have reference to this documentation or location in the code?

Comment: this should be marked as correct answer for rails 4 rspec 3.0

Comment: Docs for version Rspec 3. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/calling-the-original-implementation

Comment: Note that you probably want to do this in an `ensure` (or `after :each`) block.

Comment: This is not working for me. When I do so, the previous stub remains and the test is failing stating "expected: 0 times with any arguments, received: 1 time with arguments: ("Masterfile")"...

Answer (score 26):

The [rspec-mock](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/lib/rspec/mocks/methods.rb) code indicate that you can call the `unstub` method. I quote:

```
  # Removes a stub. On a double, the object will no longer respond to
  # `message`. On a real object, the original method (if it exists) is
  # restored.
  #
  # This is rarely used, but can be useful when a stub is set up during a
  # shared `before` hook for the common case, but you want to replace it
  # for a special case.
  def unstub(message)
    ::RSpec::Mocks.space.proxy_for(self).remove_stub(message)
  end
```